# Is the System.Timers in C# precise enough when I want to execute some code exactly every 30ms?

Tags: c#, system.timers.timer

I am using the `System.Timers.Timer` to execute a code exactly every 30ms. I am reading a value from a remote machine every 30ms, and I want to draw a curve with it.

Is the `System.Timers` execution precise enough from the trigger side? Or should I use something else? For example 1 ms tolerance would be OK for me (30ms, 29ms, 30ms, 31ms...)

Comment: Are you getting accurate data using timer?

Comment: No not acured data, i have to draw the current curve of a CNC axis in the time diagram, that should be interpreted regarding to the curve shape.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval